# Import kml file with the Fusion Tables API (v2)

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables

On the fusion tables website, when creating a new table, you can choose a .kml file. Google will automatically create a `name`, `description` and `geometry` column.

Can you accomplish the same using the [`importTable`](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/table/importTable) call in the API ? When I try uploading a kml file this way, I get the following error:

`Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError: Content is empty.[400]`

Or do I first have to create the table manually using [`insert`](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/table/insert), parse the kml file, and then use [`importRows`](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/table/importRows) call ?

Additionally: if it's possible using `ImportTable`, is there a way to retrieve the `tableId` ? It's not in the returned `ResumableUploadProgress` object.